# Append set to false, but still got warn for missing append mode, and defaulting it to true

Tags: java, logback

I have a strange problem. Got appender set to false in my **logback.xml**, but still got warn and setting it back to true.

```
|-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file] - Append mode is mandatory for RollingFileAppender. Defaulting to append=true.
```

Here is my appender:

```
<appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/test.logs</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <maxIndex>6</maxIndex>
            <FileNamePattern>logs/test.logs.%i</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>
```

**UPDATE:**
I noticed there's an Error message also, it seems it can't recognise append:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:16 - no applicable action for [append], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][append]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning message is a little bit confusing. It seems that it should be read as

> Appending is required for RollingFileAppender. Setting append=true.

You can check the [source code](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.java#L67) and see that appending will always be turned on. To get rid of the unwanted WARN/ERROR logs remove the `<append>` element from your configuration as the message hints.

Comment: It's not about the warn or error logs. I want to truncate the log file before every test run, that's why I need append to set false.

Comment: Then you can't use RollingFileAppender during development